# Export df to csv in Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, export

I am new to Django

I currently already have a df in the views.py, I pull the data from the MSSQL database which already connected.

**Views.py**

```
def CaseTest(request)
dfa_query="""
Select * from database
"""
dfa=pandas.read_sql_query(dfa_query,connection)
dfa_html=dfa.to_html(index=False,table_id='dbtable")
return render(request,'CaseTest.html')
```

**CaseTest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CaseTest</title>
</head>
<body>
{% load site_extra %}
<h2> CaseTest DF </h2>
 <div style="height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    {{itba | safe}}
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to add a button to html, when **the user** click it, they can download the df. How can I realize this. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: create another view which follows along with the pattern described at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/ and point your link at that new view (will need an entry in urls.py)

Comment: @AMG, Hi thank you for the help. But sorry I am new to Django, "creating another view" means a new views.py? I thought one app can only have one views.py?

Comment: You can have many views in the same views.py file. Each view can be tied to it's on url as well.